# Retrofit2 How do i put the / at the end of the dynamic baseUrl?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have sent and retrieved a url String from a json response using Parcelable in a fragment like so

Received String value

```
String profile_url = student.getProfile();
```

I want to use this string value as the basUrl to make another request using Retrofit like so

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(profile_url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

But getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

            ......

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /:
```

How do i put the / at the end of the baseUrl?
Putting it directly like so

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(profile_url/)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
```

does not work, Express expected.

Any help. Thanks

Debug Profile url `profile_url=http://services.hanselandstudent.com/student.svc/1.1/162137/category/1120/json?banner=0&atid=468f8dc2-9a38-487e-92ae-a194e81809d9`

Comment: Use `Endpoint` and make `Custom Endpoint Interface`

Comment: @MD, sorry, am a newbie, please guide me more. thanks

Comment: can you debug and post what is your profile_url exactly?

Comment: @xiaoyaoworm-added the debug profile-url. It's an absolute url

Comment: @Geob Can you install Advanced Rest Client extension in Chrome and copy paste your URL with GET/POST/PUT/DELETE path there to give a try to see whether you can get response. Usually this is how I make URL: Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http: //yourServerip:port/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();                       This is how interface looks like: @GET("something")   
    Call<List<Something>> getSomething();         The whole link will be http :// yourServerip:port/something

Answer (score 2):

Since you've a complete url to call, you will need the @Url annotation in Retrofit2.

Define your interface with something like that

```
public interface YourApiService {
    @GET
    Call<Profile> getProfile(@Url String url);

    class Factory {
        public static YourApiService createService() {
             Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://www.what.com/")
                .build();
             return retrofit.create(YourApiService.class);
       }
    }
}
```

Then call it with

```
YourApiService.createService().getProfile(profile_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have "/" in the end of your string variable.

```
String profile_url = student.getProfile() + "/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(profile_url)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
```

Comment: have tried that as well, same error. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: